# Object Modelling -UML or other modelling tools?

Tags: oop

Just I am new to Object Modelling.I want to know still there is a need to use Sequence Diagram, Use case Diagram to develop an object model or any other new technology is available?

Update :

CRC (Class,Responsibilites,Collaborator) is very limited ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the team or teams you're working with.  The chief benefit of UML is that you can share diagrams with other individuals and teams without having to learn each others diagramming language.  If the team you're working with doesn't know UML, it may not be worth going down that road unless everyone is interested and you know you'll be working together for a while.

In my experience UML sequence diagrams and object model diagrams are very usefully and generally understood by all.  Sequence diagrams in particular have the ability to resolve design issues through the disipline of their construction.  I haven't found use case diagrams to be as useful.  Requirements are challenging and strongly dependent on human and organizational factors regardless of the methodology.

If you're communcating with non-technical stakeholders, UML is a waste of time because they won't have studied it.  Use simple, well annotated diagrams.  Colors are very effective.

If your team is all onsite, sometimes there's nothing better than a couple of whiteboards and a freeform diagramming style.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul for spending your time to give good advice.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need these items. They are just aids which are available if you choose to utilise them. They are particularly useful in a business environment where you need to articulate your architecture to fellow developers, but you can choose to use whatever you like, inc. your own personal standards or no standards at all!

Answer (score 1):

"any other new technology is available?"

No.

UML pretty much dominates.  A classic ERD is just a specialized class diagram that omits the method box from each class.  Also, classic ERD's use crows feet instead of text annotation for cardinality and optionality.  So ERD's are actually part of UML.

You can read about [OPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Process_Methodology), if you want something slightly different.  They appear to combine an activity diagram and a class diagram into one thing: a [process-data diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process-data_diagram).

Comment: Thanks .I will go visit the wiki page.